# Two priors on the same parameter?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, stan

I received a text where the author was employing Stan language in order to show how to create a random walk with normally distributed parameters.

His model had parameters $\mu_{t}$, ($1,2,...,T$), such that, $\mu_{t}$ had a priori $N(\mu_{t-1}, 0.0025)$. He also defined $N(0.5, 0.00001)$ for $\mu_1$, and $N(0.6, 0.00001)$ for $\mu_{T}$. His code was like this:

```
data {
  int<lower=1> n_days; 
}
parameters {
  real<lower=0, upper=1> mu[n_days];               
}
model {
  mu[1]  ~ normal(0.5,0.00001);
  for (i in 2:(n_days))
      mu[i] ~ normal(mu[i - 1], 0.005);

mu[n_days] ~ normal(0.6,0.00001);
}
```

This model generated this image. 
[image: Image1]

I noticed, however, that this model indicates two different distributions for $\mu[n_days]$, $N(\mu[i-1], 0.005)$ and $N(0.6, 0.00001)$. What is happening here? Is this possible?

In order to change this possibility, I removed the second distribution using the following code:

```
data {
  int<lower=1> n_days; 
}
parameters {
  real<lower=0, upper=1> mu[n_days];               
}
model {
  mu[1]  ~ normal(0.5,0.00001);
  for (i in 2:(n_days - 1))
      mu[i] ~ normal(mu[i - 1], 0.005);

mu[n_days] ~ normal(0.6,0.00001);
}
```

However, this different graph was generated.

[image: Image2]

Why does this difference happen? Are we talking about two different prioris for the same parameter?

Comment: It also seems likely that the code mixed up the parameterization of the normal distribution in Stan, which is in terms of a mean and a standard deviation. With such small numbers for the second argument, it looks as if the code was intended to use a mean-precision parameterization of the normal distribution like in BUGS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect of the code is a 1:1 weighted mixture as the prior for that last parameter (effectively both log-likelihoods get added to the target distribution that we sample from). Whether this is deliberate or an indexing mistake (as you seemed to suspect - perhaps this is a python user?) will depend on what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

To me, since the prior $\mathcal{N}(0.6, 0.00001)$ is very informative compared to $\mathcal{N}(\mu[i - 1), 0.005$, it simply acts as data with the effect of having a trend toward 0.6.
This view that prior is data seems to be supported by Gelman (see [here](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2019/08/23/yes-you-can-include-prior-information-on-quantities-of-interest-not-just-on-parameters-in-your-model/) for example).

That's why when you remove this informative prior, you just observe the distribution of a random walk.

To comment on Bjorn' answer, I don't think including two priors would result in the mixture $0.5 \mathcal{N}(0.6, 0.00001) + 0.5 \mathcal{N}(\mu[i - 1]), 0.005)$, otherwise you would expect to get a posterior estimate for the last day between 0.5 and 0.6.